# Can NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayout support "growing cells"

Tags: macos, nscollectionview

I have a collection view showing a simple one-column list with a `NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayout`. The cells take the full width and have a fixed height.

I would like that, upon an external event, one of the cell grows in height (animated).

That could be for example :

- when the cell is selected
- when an image shown in the cell is downloaded

I found no way to do this in Apple's doc, when I think this is a fairly common use case. It seems that `NSCollectionViewCompositionalLayout` is very flexible in positioning cells, but very static. All cell sizes are computed once and for all.

Is there any API for this ? What's the way ?